# I'm trying to make an auto-updater for my app in Godot

Tags: godot, godot4

I'm creating an app in Godot, but since I don't want to always transfer the apk file to my phone I tried to make an auto-updater on my own, but, as you could have guessed, I miserably failed.

So is there a way to do it? Maybe with GitHub? Maybe with HTTPRequest?

Thanks in advance.

By the way, here's the code I tried to use (ignore the bad organization in it):

```
extends Control


@export var installed_version = "1.2"

@onready var http = $HTTPRequest

var ver_link = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GPGamer98/tpc/main/version.txt"

var dir = DirAccess

var previous_apk = "C://Users/Giacomo/tpc/tpc_%s.txt"

var to_request = "https://github.com/GPGamer98/tpc/releases/download/%s/%s.txt"

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    http.request_completed.connect(_on_request_completed)
    http.request(ver_link)



# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _process(_delta):
    pass


func _on_request_completed(_result, _response_code, _headers, body):
    print(body.get_string_from_utf8())
    
    var formatted_ver_apk = previous_apk % [installed_version]
    print("formatted ver apk: " + formatted_ver_apk)
    
    var latest_ver = body.get_string_from_utf8()
    print(typeof(latest_ver))
    print("latest ver: " + body.get_string_from_utf8())
    
    if installed_version != body.get_string_from_utf8():
        print("install and latest arent equal")
        
        print(installed_version)
        print(typeof(installed_version))
        
        print(body.get_string_from_utf8())
        print(typeof(body.get_string_from_utf8()))
        
        var request_formatted = to_request % [latest_ver, latest_ver]
        http.request(request_formatted)
        print("request: " + to_request % [latest_ver, latest_ver])
        
        var file_to_download_path = "C://Users/Giacomo/tpc/tpc_%s.txt"
        var ftdownload_formatted = file_to_download_path % [latest_ver]
        
        http.download_file = ftd_formatted
        print("downloaded: " + ftd_formatted)
        
        print(dir.dir_exists_absolute(ftd_formatted))
        OS.shell_open(ftd_formatted)
        print("opened: " + ftd_formatted)
```

Comment: What part doesn't work? There's just bunch of codes without explanation

Comment: @Cid specifically, the formatting of variables. For example, the "request_formatted" variables just replaces %s with nothing

Comment: Did you try to `print(latest_ver)` to check if it contained anything?

Comment: I tried, it printed nothing and I even tried to check its type and it was a string...